# What's TargetCreateDynamic in crm 2011

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-4

I  must convert a CRM 4 Plug-In to CRM 2011 Plug-IN. 
In my code a have a specific  class called

> TargetCreateDynamic.

```
create = new TargetCreateDynamic();
                    create.Entity = counter;
                    cRequest = new CreateRequest();
                    cRequest.Target = create;
                    cResponse = (CreateResponse)_cs.Execute(cRequest);
```

Has anybody idea which class should be this in 2011?

Comment: Added C# tag to question to make code highlight :)

Comment: In addition to the answer of @SergeyS: as each class has the base class `Entity` there is no need for distinguishing between system entities and custom entities anymore. So you could simply use a CreateRequest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use just `Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity` class for `CreateRequest`. Below sample code which will make you an idea how to make a plain CreateRequest in CRM 2011

```
    internal Guid CreateEntity(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        IOrganizationService organizationService = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(null);

        CreateRequest createRequest = new CreateRequest();
        Entity entityToCreate = new Entity("Some_Entity_LogicalName");
        createRequest.Target = entityToCreate;
        CreateResponse response = (CreateResponse)organizationService.Execute(createRequest);

        return response.id;
    }
```

But if I want to create new record for some entity in plug-in - I use following shorter code:

```
    internal Guid CreateEntity(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
        IOrganizationService organizationService = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(null);

        Entity entityToCreate = new Entity("Some_Entity_LogicalName");
        return organizationService.Create(entityToCreate);
    }
```

Please note that this is just a sample code, you do not need to create OrganizationService every time you are saving/updating/deleting some entity. You can create Organization service once for you plugin, store it in some 'global' variable and than just use it everywhere

Comment: +1, though you shouldn't really be storing the organisation service in a global variable. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328263.aspx "...you should not use global variables or attempt to store any data in member variables for use during the next plug-in invocation..."

Comment: @James Wood - Yes, I mean you can store it if you need several actions during one plugin run.